# Entity Framework DateTIme Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql

I'm having an issue with a linq subquery return invalid data when adding in datetime checks as part of the `where` clause.

This is the original query and it is returning 0; because the result set is `null`

```
var subquery = 
    (from item in g
     from e in item.Entry
    where e.Type == 1 
       && e.EntryType == 2
       && item.StartDate >= priorMonthStartOfDay
       && item.EndDate <= startOfDayQueryParam
   select e.Amount).Sum() ?? 0M;
```

I modified the query to see what the data was; here is that query and the resulting dataset.

```
var subquery = 
    (from item in g
     from e in item.Entry
    where e.Type == 1 
       && e.EntryType == 2
   select new 
          {
               Amount = e.Amount,
               SD = item.StartDate,
               ED = item.EndDate,
               QD = priorMonthStartOfDay
          };
```

[image: no date restriction results]

So then I added in the start date comparison and the results are below.  The `priorMonthStartOfDay` is a DateTime with a value of `12/1/2015 12:00:00 AM`

```
var subquery = 
    (from item in g
     from e in item.Entry
    where e.Type == 1 
       && e.EntryType == 2
       && item.StartDate >= priorMonthStartOfDay
   select new 
          {
               Amount = e.Amount,
               SD = item.StartDate,
               ED = item.EndDate,
               QD = priorMonthStartOfDay
          };
```

[image: start date restriction]

Why is the date comparison not behaving as I would expected?  Given the value of `priorMonthStartOfDay`, I would expect the result set to be the same for the last two queries.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the time equal comparison because if I subtract a second from the `priorMonthStartOfDay` then the result sets match up again.

Comment: what's the datatype of `priorMonthStartOfDay` in the last query? Is it a `string` or a `DateTime`?

Comment: @gldraphael DateTime; updated question

Comment: Can you show how do you set `priorMonthStartOfDay`? It might not be exactly what you see in the debugger.

Comment: maybe the `en.Amount` is confusing it since you haven't defined what `en` actually is, or you're not showing us the full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only logical explanation could be that your `priorMonthStartOfDay` and/or `startOfDayQueryParam` variables contain time part not shown in the debugger. Note that by default milliseconds part is not shown, not to mention ticks.

To be 100% sure you are comparing against **dates**, change the date part of the criteria to

```
&& item.StartDate >= priorMonthStartOfDay.Date
&& item.EndDate <= startOfDayQueryParam.Date
```

Comment: It was the ticks.  They were off by 1; I had checked the milliseconds, and I had even looked at the ticks, but apparently not close enough.